# Test for file existence only work for exactly 1 file, how to have it work for 2 files?

Tags: files

If I have any a single xyz.PDF file this works:

```
[ -e *.PDF* ] && echo 'yes'
```

However if I have two files, e.g.

```
xyz.PDF
abc.PDF
```

I get

```
$ [ -e *.PDF* ] && echo 'yes'
-bash: [: sometstgg.PDF: binary operator expected
```

How to get around this and allow for either 1 or many files?

Answer (score 0):

```
set -- *.PDF

[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && [ "$*" != "*.PDF" ] && echo 'yes'
```

There probably is a better solution as this would fail if there is something with the actual name `*.PDF` there.

For `bash` I think it would be enough with

```
shopt -s nullglob
set -- *.PDF

[[ "$#" -gt 0 ]] && echo yes
```

In `ksh93`, this seems to be enough:

```
[ -e *.PDF ] && echo yes
```